# can I use route() to make a DELETE request in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm using laravel and trying to delete something. Is it possible to specify the DELETE method on laravel's route()??

e.g

```
route('dashboard-delete-user', ['id' => $use->id, 'method'=> 'delete'])
```

or something like that??

EDIT:
What I meant was could I specify that in a link or a button in my blade template. Similar to this:

```
href="{{ route('dashboard-delete-user') }}
```

Comment: Yes you can [take a look here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#basic-routing) you can use the `route::delete()` method.

Comment: No you can't do that with route only.... Have a look at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/delete-method-with-href

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this:

```
Route::delete($uri, $callback);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#basic-routing

**Update**

If for some reason you want to use route only (without a controller), you can use closure, something like:

```
Route::get('delete-user/{id}', function ($id) {
    App\User::destroy($id);
    return 'User '.$id.' deleted';
});
```

Comment: this is not what the askers intention is about... The question boils down to: "Is it possible to have a link within an <a> tag that addresses a DELETE route. ( Without use of forms )

Comment: Well, OP added this info after I've answered. Now, I've updated my answer with solution OP might use.

Comment: Your updated solution will work, but I won't recommend it, as it totally bypasses any CSRF Protection for that routes. Get should only be used for displaying data.

Answer (score 0):

No or at least I haven't figure out how to.

The only way for this to work out of the box would be to build a form to handle it.  At the very minimum, you would need...

```
<form action="{{ route('dashboard-delete-user') }}" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or you can just create the get route which you are trying to link to and have it handle the logic.  It doesn't *need* to be a route which only respondes to `delete` requests to delete a resource.

Comment: Although id does not need to be declared as a DELETE route, it is common practice not using HTTP GET  for deleting (updating or creating)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, using a URL helper. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#urls

There are several options to choose from.

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote... This is exactly what OP needed.